# Javascript : External Functions won't work

Tags: javascript, html

I have been using javascript for the last couple of days and have decided to use it for my website. I also decided to use external functions in a single .js file

```
function imageLoad() {
    var path,domain,cut;
    path = window.location.pathname;
    domain = "WEBSITE DOMAIN ADDRESS";

    cut = path.substring(domain.length,path.length);

    /* Still in progress */
}

function pageStart() {
    var image-on = 0;
    var imgArray = new Array();

    alert("boo"); /* Used to check the script will run */
}
```

Now that's a simple process. Nothing too complex. And I have done the following (it is a code extract of my template)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main_script.js"></script>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>Grandpa Pixel</title>
</head>

<body onload="pageStart();">
```

Now that should do the trick. On body loading, it should cause an alert "boo". But it doesn't. It just loads the page normally. However If I make the external script ONLY contain the line alert("boo"), it works perfectly. Can I ask why this is the case? Does this mean you can only have one function per external file?

Comment: Syntax error `var image-on = 0;` ?

Comment: This would be a good time to learn how the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) works.

Comment: I don't think having the script element before the head is correct, too.

Comment: see web console errors

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
function pageStart() {
    var image_on = 0;
    var imgArray = new Array();

    alert("boo"); /* Used to check the script will run */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>Grandpa Pixel</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main_script.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="pageStart();">
```

Answer (score 0):

recommended using Firebug or other debuggers.

ERRORS

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
var image-on = 0;

main_script.js (line 12, col 13)

ReferenceError: pageStart is not defined

pageStart();
```

SOLUTION

change

```
var image-on = 0;
```

with

```
var imageOn = 0;
```

it would be cleaner to put the <script> tag into the <header> tag.